# Can't get onclick $(this).addClass to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I just can't get the clicked link to change class and show as active link

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kAW4g/

```
$(".navul a").on('click', function(e) {

    $(this).addClass("navhover");

});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The jQuery code works, the issue is that your CSS rule is not specific enough to override the default `background-color`, try this:

```
.navul a.navhover { // <--more specific selector
    color: blue;
    background-color: #6eff97;
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kAW4g/5/)

Also, your fiddle was not working because you did not include jQuery in the page via the dropdown on the left.

Comment: It's magic! Damn, these small things can cause headaches.. Thank you :D